# Iterating through multiple feature layers in a python toolbox tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

This script accepts feature layers as a multivalue pararameter but it is not iterating through the layers to add fields for each.  How can I fix this script to use the multiple feature layers that it is passed?

```
import arcpy    

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Field Creation"
        self.alias = "Field Creation"

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [MigrateFromPointToPolygon]


class MigrateFromPointToPolygon(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Field Creation"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
         displayName="Input Features",
         name="in_features",
         datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
         parameterType="Required",
         direction="Input",
         multiValue=True) 
          
        params =[param0]
       
        return params

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""  
            
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""    

        input_features=parameters[0]

        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
       fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

       for input_polygon in fclist:
        #input_polygon = parameters[0].valueAsText

        
            arcpy.env.overwriteOutput="true"
            #creating an iteration parameters
            
            #increment values
            p=0
            i = 0
        
    
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input_polygon,"polygonlayer")
            #messages.addMessage("Made feature layers")

            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"Lv_NUMBER", "TEXT", 11)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"ENCL", "TEXT", 9)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"AREA", "TEXT", 20)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"LOT_NUMBER", "TEXT", 15)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"VOL_FOL", "TEXT", 15)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"DP_NUMBER", "TEXT", 10)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"PE_NUMBER", "TEXT", 15)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"R_NUMBER", "TEXT", 10)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"CAD_NUMBER", "TEXT", 15)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"L_NUMBER", "TEXT", 15)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"PAR_NUMBER", "TEXT", 15)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"CATEGORY", "TEXT", 1)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"PLACENAME", "TEXT", 50)
                            #cursor.updateRow(feature)

            return
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. It would be helpful to provide an introduction to the problem, a question within the body of the text, and a short, descriptive question in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your script accepts multiple inputs, but you never use them.
2. You shouldn't need to create a new layer, your script only accepts GPFeatureLayer
3. You return inside your `for` loop so it only executes once

Try something like:

```
etc...

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):

        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput="true"
        
        for polygonlayer in parameters[0].values:
    
            messages.addMessage(polygonlayer.name)

            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"Lv_NUMBER", "TEXT", 11)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"ENCL", "TEXT", 9)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"AREA", "TEXT", 20)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"LOT_NUMBER", "TEXT", 15)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"VOL_FOL", "TEXT", 15)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"DP_NUMBER", "TEXT", 10)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"PE_NUMBER", "TEXT", 15)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"R_NUMBER", "TEXT", 10)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"CAD_NUMBER", "TEXT", 15)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"L_NUMBER", "TEXT", 15)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"PAR_NUMBER", "TEXT", 15)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"CATEGORY", "TEXT", 1)
            arcpy.AddField_management(polygonlayer,"PLACENAME", "TEXT", 50)

        return
```

Comment: it works thanks a million @user2856